# Symfony2 - Username & roles in Twig templates with custom authenticator

Tags: php, security, symfony, authentication, twig

I'm using a custom authenticator to validate login credentials using a 3rd party service.

When I try to access `{{ app.user }}` within twig it's not defined.  If I access `{{ app.security.token.user }}` I get the username as a string.

I need to access the roles for the current user, but as the app.user is not set I don't know how to do this.

In the profiler, the user and their roles are shown, so they must be available somewhere.

Any ideas Why they might not be available, or how else I can access this information?

#### Authenticator Class

```
<?php

namespace Client\AdminBundle\Security;


use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Client\AdminBunde\Entity\User;
use Client\AdminBunde\Exception\RuntimeException;
use Client\AdminBunde\Entity\Client;
use Client\AdminBunde\Entity\ClientRepository;
use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleClient;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;
use GuzzleHttp\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\SimpleFormAuthenticatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;

class CustomAuthenticator implements SimpleFormAuthenticatorInterface
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $rolesMap;

    /**
     * @var ClientRepository
     */
    protected $clientRepository;

    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $entityManager;

    /**
     * @param array            $rolesMap
     * @param ClientRepository $clientRepository
     * @param EntityManager    $entityManager
     */
    public function __construct( $rolesMap, ClientRepository $clientRepository, EntityManager $entityManager )
    {
        $this->rolesMap         = $rolesMap;
        $this->clientRepository = $clientRepository;
        $this->entityManager    = $entityManager;
    }


    /**
     * @param TokenInterface        $token
     * @param UserProviderInterface $userProvider
     * @param                       $providerKey
     *
     * @throws RuntimeException if response is not set by the time needed
     *
     * @return UsernamePasswordToken
     */
    public function authenticateToken( TokenInterface $token, UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $providerKey )
    {
        $username = $token->getUsername();
        $password = $token->getCredentials();
        $user     = new User;
        $user->setUsername( $username )
             ->setPassword( $password );

        $uri = 'http://example.com/sso-integration/auth' .
               '?userId=' . urlencode( $user->getUsername() ) .
               "&passwordHash=" . urlencode( $user->getPassword() );

        try {
            $response = $this->guzzleGet( $uri );
        } catch ( RequestException $e ) {
            $reason = @$e->getResponse()->getReasonPhrase();
            if ( ! empty( $reason )) {
                throw new AuthenticationException( 'Unable to login.  ' . $reason . '.' );
            }
        } catch ( \Exception $e ) {
            throw new AuthenticationException( 'Unable to login.  Please try again.' );
        }

        if (empty( $response )) {
            throw new RuntimeException( 'No response' );
        }

        if (200 != $response->getStatusCode()) {
            throw new AuthenticationException(
                'There was a problem connecting to the authentication service.  Please try again.'
            );
        }

        $responseJson = @$response->json();

        if (empty( $responseJson['status'] )) {
            throw new AuthenticationException(
                'There was a problem connecting to the authentication service.  Please try again.'
            );
        }

        if ('OK' !== $responseJson['status']) {
            $msg = ! empty( $responseJson['message'] ) ? $responseJson['message'] : 'Incorrect credentials';
            throw new AuthenticationException( $msg );
        }

        if (empty( $responseJson['roles'] )) {
            throw new AuthenticationException( 'Authenticated, but with no role.  Please try again.' );
        }

        $returnedRoles = $responseJson['roles'];
        if ( ! is_array( $returnedRoles )) {
            $returnedRoles = [ $returnedRoles ];
        }

        $roles = [ ];
        foreach ($returnedRoles as $role) {
            if ( ! empty( $this->rolesMap[$role] )) {
                $roles[] = $this->rolesMap[$role];
            }
        }

        if (empty( $roles )) {
            throw new AuthenticationException( 'Authenticated, but with no role.  Please try again.' );
        }

        $client = @$this->clientRepository->findOneByUsername( $username );

        if (empty( $client )) {
            $client = new Client;
            $client->setUsername( $username )
                   ->setName( $username );
            $this->entityManager->persist( $client );
            $this->entityManager->flush();
        }

        $user->setClient( $client );
        $user->setRoles( $roles );

        $token = new ClientUsernamePasswordToken(
            $user->getUsername(),
            $user->getPassword(),
            $providerKey,
            $user->getRoles()
        );

        return $token;
    }

    /**
     * Indicates if this class can authenticate a given token
     *
     * @param TokenInterface $token
     * @param                $providerKey
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function supportsToken( TokenInterface $token, $providerKey )
    {
        return $token instanceof ClientUsernamePasswordToken;
    }

    /**
     * Creates the user token with user's login credentials
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param string  $username
     * @param string  $password
     * @param         $providerKey
     *
     * @return UsernamePasswordToken
     */
    public function createToken( Request $request, $username, $password, $providerKey )
    {
        return new ClientUsernamePasswordToken( $username, $password, $providerKey );
    }

    /**
     * @param $uri
     *
     * @return ResponseInterface
     */
    protected function guzzleGet( $uri )
    {
        $guzzleClient = new GuzzleClient();
        /** @noinspection PhpVoidFunctionResultUsedInspection */
        $response = $guzzleClient->get( $uri );

        return $response;
    }
}
```

#### Token Class

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: toby
 * Date: 17/07/2014
 * Time: 23:51
 */

namespace Client\AdminBundle\Security;


use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;

class ClientUsernamePasswordToken extends UsernamePasswordToken
{
}
```

#### services.yml

```
parameters:
    client.security.authenticator.class: Client\AdminBundle\Security\ClientAuthenticator
    client.form.type.client.class: Client\AdminBundle\Form\Type\ClientType
    client.form.type.client_own.class: Client\AdminBundle\Form\Type\ClientOwnType
    client.form.type.app.class: Client\AdminBundle\Form\Type\AppType
    client.form.type.gallery.class: Client\AdminBundle\Form\Type\GalleryType
    client.form.type.colour.class: Client\AdminBundle\Form\Type\ColourType
    client.form.type.image.class: Client\AdminBundle\Form\Type\ImageType
    client.image: Client\AdminBundle\Service\Image
    client.image.sizes: []
    client.image.upload_subscriber.class: Client\AdminBundle\EventListener\ImageUploadDoctrineEventListener
    client.cdn.aws_s3.class: Client\AdminBundle\File\AWSS3
    client.event_listener.new_image.class: Client\AdminBundle\EventListener\NewImageEventListener
    client.file.path_calculator.class: Client\AdminBundle\File\PathCalculator
    client.eventlistener.admin_cache_prevention.class: Client\AdminBundle\EventListener\AdminCachePreventionEventSubscriber
    client.eventlistener.varnish_cache_clear.class: Client\AdminBundle\EventListener\VarnishCacheClearListener

services:
    client.security.authenticator:
        class: %client.security.authenticator.class%
        arguments: [%client.user_roles%, @client.repository.client, @doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager]

    client.form.type.client:
        class: %client.form.type.client.class%
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: client }

    client.form.type.client_own:
        class: %client.form.type.client_own.class%
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: client_own }

    client.form.type.app:
        class: %client.form.type.app.class%
        calls:
            - [setImageService, [@client.image]]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: app }

    client.form.type.gallery:
        class: %client.form.type.gallery.class%
        calls:
            - [setAppRepository, [@client.repository.app]]
            - [setImageService, [@client.image]]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: gallery }

    client.form.type.colour:
        class: %client.form.type.colour.class%
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: colour }

    client.form.type.image:
        class: %client.form.type.image.class%
        calls:
            - [setImageService, [@client.image]]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: image }

    client.image:
        class: %client.image%
        calls:
            - [setRouter, [@router.default]]
            - [setEventDispatcher, [@event_dispatcher]]
            - [setCdn, [@client.cdn.aws_s3]]
            - [setSizes, [%client.image.sizes%]]
            - [setImageQuality, [%client.images.resize_quality%]]

    client.image.upload_subscriber:
        class: %client.image.upload_subscriber.class%
        calls:
            - [setImageService, [@client.image]]
            - [setEventDispatcher, [@event_dispatcher]]
            - [setPathCalculator, [@client.file.path_calculator]]
            - [setLogger, [@monolog.logger]]
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: uploadablePostFileProcess }

    client.cdn.aws_s3:
        class: %client.cdn.aws_s3.class%
        arguments: [@aws_s3, %aws_s3_images_bucket%, %aws_cloudfront_domains%]
        calls:
            - [setRequestStack, [@request_stack]]

    client.event_listener.new_image:
        class: %client.event_listener.new_image.class%
        calls:
            - [setCdn, [@client.cdn.aws_s3]]
            - [setPathCalculator, [@client.file.path_calculator]]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }

    client.file.path_calculator:
        class: %client.file.path_calculator.class%
        calls:
            - [setWebRoot, [%webroot%]]

    client.eventlistener.admin_cache_prevention:
        class: %client.eventlistener.admin_cache_prevention.class%
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }

    client.eventlistener.varnish_cache_clear:
        class: %client.eventlistener.varnish_cache_clear.class%
        calls:
            - [setContainer, [@service_container]]
            - [setRouter, [@router.default]]
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber }
```

#### security.yml

```
security:
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    # Users now handled by Client SSO integration
#                    ryan:  { password: ryanpass, roles: 'ROLE_USER' }
#                    admin: { password: kittens, roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN' }
#                    disco-superuser: { password: flxpwd, roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN' }

    role_hierarchy:
        #...

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        secured_area:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~
            simple_form:
                authenticator: client.security.authenticator
                login_path: login
                check_path: login_check
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                default_target_path:  login_redirect
            remember_me:
                key:      "%secret%"
                lifetime: 31536000 # 365 days in seconds
                path:     /
                domain:   ~ # Defaults to the current domain from $_SERVER
            logout:
                path:   logout
                target: login

    access_control:
        # ...

    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to username then you have access to roles also because `{{ app.security.token }}` is returning [TokenInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/TokenInterface.html) (see Api Reference). Then you can get roles in your template `{{ app.security.token.getRoles() }}` or `$token->getUsername();` in your method.

Comment: But app.user is not defined.  From my original post... "When I try to access {{ app.user }} within twig it's not defined".  I can only access the user name using {{ app.security.token.user }}  :o(

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. You should call {{ app.security.token.getRoles() }} instead {{ app.user.token.getRoles() }}.

Comment: Awesome!  That sorted is. Actually using the 'roles' shorthand & works perfectly.  Thanks :o)

Answer (score 0):

Is the page You are trying to reach protected by firewall? By default only on such a pages user will be accessible from templates.

Comment: Yes.  I'm trying to display the user name within a firewall protected area

Answer (score 0):

`{{ app.security.token.user }}` comes from security context. `{{ app.user }}` comes from user provider. They can be mapped. Did you set up [the user provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers) correctly? I see that you have a `User` entity configured, so in your case `app/config/security.yml` should have something similar to this I guess:

```
security:
    providers:
        main:
            entity:
                class: Client\AdminBunde\Entity\User
                property: username
```

Comment: The user object does not come from the d/b.  From reading the Symfony2 docs on that link you included, the 'entity' provider is for use with users stored in the d/b.  In this instance, the username & password are added to the User class, which then validates them against a 3rd party service, but never stores them anywhere, so not sure if this is appropriate.  There's mention of a 'custom User Provider', but this doesn't seem to have a way to pass in the user provided password (to hash & pass to the 3rd party service)?

Comment: I tried adding this, but get the error "Class "Flexion\DiscoveryComponentAdminBundle\Entity\User" is not a valid entity or mapped super class"

Comment: @TobyG Read carefully, I was not talking about **entity** provider but about **user** provider which, according to the doc, is anything that provides one or more users to the authentication system. But OK, this might not me the case here. Let me check on that other issue. In the meantime can you tell if the `User` class implements `UserInterface`?

Comment: Yes, it implements the UserInterface class, however I do have a working solution from Artem Zhuravlev's answer above, so please don't put yourself out... but I'm happy to learn more if you're able to enlighten me :o)

Comment: That's great :) However I'm still curious why `app.user` is not set in your case.

Comment: @TobyG What do you have in `services.yml` under `services:` and in `security.yml` under `security.providers:`?